# React onclick function log executes when the same state is set after updating the set previously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

```
import React from "react"
import { useState } from "react"

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState({ c: 0 })
  console.log(new Date().toString())
  console.log(`Object output ${count.c}`)

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{new Date().toString()}</p>
      {console.log(new Date().toString())};
      <br />
      <p>You clicked Object counter {count.c} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount({ ...count, c: count.c + 1 })}>
        Click me
      </button>
      <p>You clicked Object counter {count.c} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In the above React code after updating the count by clicking the first button executes log and re-renders but immediately after that clicking on second button for the first time executes the console logs in the function but do not re-render the component as the date value remains the same for this event and further click on the second button do not execute this log can anyone explain why?

Edit: explain why console logs are executed when there is no state change in second button?
(note: this happens only when first button is clicked before this which changes the state and also console logs for second button is logged only for its first click)
[Console-logs-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXvEH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `setCount(count)` you don't change the state, React rerenders only on state change ([shallow comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is)).

Doing `setCount({...count})` will rerender with the same data.

Read more on [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)

Comment: that is the doubt here there is no rerender for setCount(count) but the console logs are all logged in the console for only first click on this button after the button which change the state is clicked.

Comment: Dennis Vash is correct - React is not actually comparing the contents of the count object. Also, simply calling setState isn’t enough on its own to trigger a rerender . Dennis Vash suggests you spread the count in the setState call - what this will do is create a copy of the count object with a new object reference. When React receives the new object reference (even though the object is identical) it will rerender. This is the basics of immutably updating state in React

Comment: so even if I have to set same state for that button click do I have to always set new copy of that state by using spread operator?

Comment: Well, yes, but why do you want to do that? Why do you want a button that rerenders the component, but doesn’t actually change anything?

Comment: this is just simulation for sometimes when there is no response from server the state has to be returned unchanged for parent component when using dispatcher

Comment: But if you aren’t changing the state, why do you need the component to rerender?